# Don't get error message if login name is wrong, just blank div, but I can detect wrong password if username is correct

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys, I have a problem. I don't get error message if login name is wrong, just blank div, but I can detect wrong password if username is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" >
<head>
 <title>Login | JM Today </title>
 <link href="Mainstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <?php include("header.php"); ?>
 <?php include("navbar.php"); ?>
 <?php include("cleanquery.php") ?>  

 <div id="wrap">

    <?php

  $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db('jmtdy', $conn) or die(mysql_error());
  $check=checklogin();
  if($check == true){
   confirmcookie($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']);
  } 

  function checklogin() {
   if(isset($_COOKIE['cookname']) && isset($_COOKIE['cookpass'])){

        $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['cookname'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $_COOKIE['cookpass'];
        return true;
      }

      elseif(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){
       if((strlen($_POST['user']) > 0) && (strlen($_POST['pass']) > 0)){
        $user= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $pass= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $result=mysql_query("select password from users where username='$user' and active='1'");
        $dbArray=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select username from users where username='$user' and active='1'")) or die(mysql_error());
        $dbArray['username']= mysql_real_escape_string($dbArray['username']);

        if($dbArray['username'] != $user){
         $msg='<p class="statusmsg">The username you entered is incorrect, or you haven\'t yet activated your account. Please try again.</p><br/>';
         $status="NOTOK";
        }
       }

       else{
        $msg=$msg.'<p class="statusmsg">You didn\'t fill in the required fields.</p><br/>';
        $status="NOTOK";
       } 


       if($status != "NOTOK"){
        $dbArray=mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
        $dbArray['password']=mysql_real_escape_string($dbArray['password']);


        if($dbArray['password'] == $pass){
      $_SESSION['username']=$user;
         $_SESSION['password']=$password;
        }
        else{
         $msg=$msg.'<p class="statusmsg">The password you entered is incorrect.</p>';
         $status="NOTOK";

         }

        if(isset($_POST['remember']) && $status!="NOTOK"){
         setcookie("cookname", $_SESSION['username'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
          setcookie("cookpass", $_SESSION['password'], time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
         }
        }
        if($status=="NOTOK"){
         echo $msg . '<input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
         }
        else{
         echo '<p class="statusmsg"> You have succesfully logged in! </p>'; 
         }
       }
       else{
        echo '<p class="statusmsg"> You came here by mistake, didn\'t you? </p>';
       }

      } 


      function confirmcookie($username, $password){

     $result = mysql_query("select password from users where username = '$username'");

     if(!$result || (mysql_num_rows($result) < 1)){
      unset($_SESSION['username']);
      unset($_SESSION['password']);
        $msg=$msg.'<p class="statusmsg">The username you entered is incorrect or you have set an incorrect cookie</p>';
        $status="NOTOK";
     }

     $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
     $dbarray['password']  = cleanQuery($dbarray['password']);
     $password = cleanQuery($password);

     if($password!=$dbarray['password']){
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['password']);
        $msg=$msg.'<p class="statusmsg">The password you entered is incorrect or you have set an incorrect cookie.</p>'; 
        $status="NOTOK";
     }
     if($status == "NOTOK" ){
      echo $msg;
      }
     else{
      header('Refresh: 5; URL="homepage.php"'); 
  }
    }


  ?>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Too much code. Restructure with logic at top and then presentation.

Comment: To get the best kind of help you really need to make more effort in narrowing your problem down and asking a single and precise question. Your main goal right now should be to improve your debugging skills.

Comment: For security reasons, you should not have different error messages to say that the password is wrong or that the username is wrong. Any speculative hacker could then identify that they had "guessed" a valid username, and then only needed to guess their password. If both error messages are the same, they have no idea whether the username is wrong, the password is wrong, or both are wrong.

Comment: Don't store passwords in COOKIES, especially not in plain text

Comment: Your login is very insecure. I just have to set 2 cookies cookname+cookpass(cookies can be manipulated by a user) and im logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume that you always get a resultset for

```
select password from users where username='$user' and active='1'
```

there is no branch if it doesn't.

Leave the whole thing if

```
mysql_num_rows($result)
```

returns 0