# Login script problem

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't get error message if login name is wrong, just blank div, but I can detect wrong password if username is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518100/dont-get-error-message-if-login-name-is-wrong-just-blank-div-but-i-can-detect)

I have been trying to get this code to work, I changed it from how it was previously.  Could you please discover the problem? If the sign in is correct I still get "The username or password is incorrect."
Please help here  is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Login | JM Today </title>
    <link href="Mainstyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("navbar.php"); ?>
    <?php include("cleanquery.php") ?>  

    <div id="wrap">

       <?php
       ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);

        $conn=mysql_connect("localhost", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('jmtdy', $conn) or die(mysql_error());

        if(( strlen($_POST['user']) >0) && (strlen($_POST['pass']) >0) && isset($_POST['sublogin'])) {

            checklogin($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);

        }
        elseif(( strlen($_POST['user']) ==0) || (strlen($_POST['pass']) ==0)){

            echo '<p class="statusmsg">You didn\'t fill in the required fields.</p><br/><input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
            return;
        }
        else{

            echo '<p class="statusmsg">You came here by mistake, didn\'t you?</p><br/><input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
            return;

        }   

      function checklogin($username, $password){

        $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);

            $result=mysql_query("select username from users where username = '$username'");
            if($result != false){

                $dbArray=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $dbArray['password']=mysql_real_escape_string($dbArray['password']);
                $dbArray['username']=mysql_real_escape_string($dbArray['username']);

                if(($dbArray['password'] != $password ) || ($dbArray['username'] != $username)){
                    echo '<p class="statusmsg">The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.</p><br/><input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
                    return;
                }
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                $_SESSION['password']=$password;

                if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                    setcookie("jmuser",$_SESSION['username'],time()+60*60*24*356);  
                    setcookie("jmpass",$_SESSION['username'],time()+60*60*24*356);
                }
            }

            else{
                echo'<p class="statusmsg">  The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.</p><br/>input type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
                return;
            }
        }           


      ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is the 4th time you've asked the same question. Please do not open another question - you need to respond to the comments on the first question you asked. Please read the Stack Overflow FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I also just read your other questions, no-one here will help you if you don't help yourself. The answer is obvious.

Comment: It's because I changed the code, and the problem is also different.

Comment: @Samir, since the problem domain is the same, you should just update the original question with new code, and indicate there that it has been updated.  Keeps things tidier.

Comment: @Samir Ghobril The problem stems from the multitude of issues people have previously pointed out to you. To be honest, I'd really recommend buying a good beginners PHP book or finding a good tutorial online and get a sound understanding of the basics, otherwise you're just wasting your own (and indeed everyone else's) time.

Answer (score 1):

You're only selecting the `username` from your database, yet you're trying to compare the `password` with a non-existent returned result.  You need to select the `password` as well or the comparison with the supplied password will always be either false or an error.

**Edit:** Also, I just realized that you seem to be storing passwords in plain text.  [Please don't do that](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql_real_escape_string before you pass the username to the database. Otherwise the code is vulnerable to SQL Injections. 
The issue is that you aren't pulling the password in the select.